# RTF files created using the 'touch' command will not open

Tags: terminal, snow-leopard

I'm no expert on CLI or using the terminal or anything, but I like playing around with my computer.

When I create a .txt .html or .md file or whatever using the 'touch' command in terminal, they work fine. But .rtf file I create just give me the error

"The document “foo.rtf” could not be opened."

What am I doing wrong? Are you not able to create files in this manner?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you've likely discovered, `touch`ing a nonexistent file will create a zero-byte file with the name you specify.  (`touch` is also used to update the modification time on an existing file.  See [`man touch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/touch.1.html) for further details.)

The problem you're running into is that though a completely empty file is valid HTML, text, or Markdown, it is *not* valid RTF—this is true of many file formats, actually, which are structured in a particular way and require some data to be present be valid.

Based on my experimentation, the bare minimum RTF file appears to be

```
{\rtf1}
```

If you'd like to create a blank RTF file from the shell, try this:

```
echo '{\rtf1}' >Foo.rtf
```

Note the above will overwrite `Foo.rtf` if it exists.

Comment: Thank you, @zigg. I really appreciate that you explain the reasoning behind this. If I may ask for my own understanding, what is happening with {\rtf1}? Is that setting some sort of data about the file?

Comment: I believe all RTF documents use it as the top-level construct.  Try saving out an RTF document and using the `cat` command to dump it to the screen—every one I've seen starts with `{\rtf1`.